# Deleted row gets added again after deleting DataTable(1.10.8)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have used row.remove(); but if am on 3rd page and delete a row form 3rd page it shows again when goes to 2nd and comes back to 3rd page.

row = $(deleteParent).closest("tr").get(0);
$(row).remove();

I have deleted that row from backend (database) through ajax but why it seems in the datatable if i refresh datatable then that row is removed permanently.

i have also tried

var aaa = oTable.DataTable();
aaa.row(row).remove().draw();

but it redirect me to the first page of the datatable can any body tell me how to prevent going to first page.

Answer (score 1):

You're very nearly there, just need to pass `false` to the `draw()` function like this:

```
$('#example').on("click", "button", function(){
        table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
});
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/7c0v1ra3/

Please make sure you only delete the row in the front-end when you know for certain it's deleted from the back-end :-)

Comment: This might also be a useful reference: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: I have also tried this but this also doesn't  work for me and thanks for ur reply